# Free jqGrid 4.8.0 - How to get the gridId from within the field formatter

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Is there a way to extract the gridId from within the formatter, unformat functions on the colModel?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formatter will be called with 3 parameters `cellValue`, `options` and `rowData` and `this` initialized to DOM of the grid. To get grid id you can use `this.id` or `options.gid`. In case of usage `unformat` callback the `option` contains less properties, but one can still use `this.id`.